# Select-String -Quiet not returning True

Tags: powershell, netstat, select-string

My script is supposed to get the TCP connection information for VNC and tell me when the connection state is `ESTABLISHED`. I'm stuck on trying to get a return value of `True` when using `Select-String -Quiet`.

```
PS C:\> $vnc = netstat -ab | select-string "winvnc4.exe" -context 1,0
PS C:\> $vnc

    TCP    0.0.0.0:5800           User:0               LISTENING
>  [winvnc4.exe]
    TCP    0.0.0.0:5900           User:0               LISTENING
>  [winvnc4.exe]
    TCP    [::]:5800              User:0               LISTENING
>  [winvnc4.exe]
    TCP    [::]:5900              User:0               LISTENING
>  [winvnc4.exe]

PS C:\> $vnc | Select-String "LISTENING" -quiet

PS C:\> $vnc | Select-String -Pattern "LISTENING" -quiet

PS C:\> $vnc | Select-String "LISTENING" -simplematch -quiet
```

As you can see, I tried several different parameters to get a result but nothing is returned.

Comment: Your code works as expected for me: I see "True" being returned. Have you omitted any code, no matter how unimportant?

Comment: This is everything. I even closed out ISE and re-opened as Administrator (like it was the first time I tried) and it still didn't return anything.
`PS C:\> get-host | select Version
Version      
-------      
5.0.10586.494`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `Select-String` produces a list of [`MatchInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects. The information you're after is stored in the `Context` property of these. You need to expand that before you can run another `Select-String` on it.

```
$vnc | Select-Object -Expand Context |
    Select-Object -Expand PreContext |
    Select-String 'LISTENING' -SimpleMatch -Quiet
```

On PowerShell v3 and newer you can use [member enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/) to make that a little more compact:

```
$vnc | ForEach-Object { $_.Context.PreContext } |
    Select-String 'LISTENING' -SimpleMatch -Quiet
```